# Wrong citizenship on my ETORO account

Tags: taxes, brokerage, citizenship

ETORO took my country of tax residency as my country of citizenship and this is not True. What should I do? Their customer support seems useless. Can I continue with it?

Comment: Is either of the countries the US?

Comment: @TooTea No Australia